# A recurrent sequence related to the Brouwer fixed-point theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

Let $K$ be a non-empty compact convex subset of a Banach space $E$, and let $f : K \longmapsto K$ be a continuous function. Fix $u_0 \in K$, and define by recurrence $u_{n+1} = \frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{j=0}^n f(u_j)$ ; or equivalently $u_{n+1} - u_n = \frac{1}{n+1} (f(u_n) -u_n)$.

> Is it always true that $(u_n)$ converges to some fixed point of $f$ ?

- When $E$ is one-dimensional, this is an easy exercise, but all proofs I know use in a crucial way the ordering of the real numbers.
- I don't expect the two-dimensional case to be easier than the general case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A counterexample in dimension $2$: take $K$ the unit closed disk of $\mathbb{C}$, and $f:K\to K$ the map
$$f(z)=e^{i\pi/4}\frac{z}{|z|}\min(2|z|,1)$$ 
for $z\neq0$, and $f(0)=0$, which is the only fixed point of $f$. Then, starting by $u_0\in K$ with $|u _ 0|\ge1/2$ produces a sequence with $|u_n|\ge 1/2$. (Reason: if $|u_n|\ge1/2$ then  $u_ {n+1}$ lies in the segment of endpoints $u _ n$ and $f(u_n)=e^{i\pi/4}\frac{u _ n}{|u _ n|}$, a segment that is disjoint from the disk  $B(0,1/2)$, by elementary geometry considerations).

Comment: If we start with $u_0 = 1$ then $u_1 = i$ and $u_2 = (i-1)/2$ so that $u_2$ is in the interior of $K$.

Comment: More precisely, $|u_n|$ is $\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ in your example.

Comment: Sorry. I think it is fixed now.

Comment: Thanks ! This also yield counterexamples in any dimension.